# Powershell concat double black-slash with variable (dollar sign)

Tags: powershell

I want to substitute the variable into computer path..

```
Write-Host \\$store.storeIp\$Global:config.dest
```

**Expected**

```
\\127.0.0.1\D$\foo
```

**Actual**

```
\\@{storeNumber=1111; storeName=CAT; storeIp=127.0.0.1; status=FAILED}.storeIp\@{inputFile=./store-deployment-inp
ut.csv; src=.\foo; dest=D$\foo; destDir=D:; installerFileName=xxx.exe; po=; serviceName=xxx; forceDeploy=False; legacyScript=}.dest
```

Somehow, look like the powershell output all the object instead of output the select value when in conjuction with \$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this like this:

```
Write-Host ("\\{0}\{1}" -f $store.storeIp, $Global:config.dest)
```

Or since it's a path:

```
Join-Path $store.storeIp $Global:config.dest
```

Comment: Join-Path not works for me but the first is. Thanks!